# How to install typings programmatically

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to install `typings` from my `build.js` file.

For example, to install my `bower` deps I use:

```
var bower = require("bower");
bower.commands.install();
```

Is it possible to install `typings` that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so, but as an alternative, you could probably get away with using [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to run it.

If you have Typings installed globally, something along these lines should work:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var typings = spawn("typings", ["install"], { shell: true });
```

Or if you have it installed locally:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var typings = spawn("./node_modules/.bin/typings", ["install"], { shell: true });
```

I'd recommend reading the [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) docs to learn how to pipe the output from stdout/stderr to your build script - otherwise it'll run silently, I think.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way not to install typings globally?

Comment: @Veikedo: `npm install typings` should do the trick. If it's installed locally, you'll need to replace the `"typings"` in my answer with `"./node_modules/.bin/typings"`.

Comment: @Veikedo: Updated my answer accordingly!

Comment: @Veikedo: Whoops, that should have been `npm install typings --save-dev`, so it ends up in your `package.json` file.